# How to define a single legend for a set of subplots on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

This may seem like a duplicate, but I swear I tried to find a compatible answer.

I have a set of histograms of different properties of the same 3 samples. So I want a legend with the name of these tree samples.

I tried defining the same labels('h1','h2' and 'h3') in all histograms, like this:

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.hist(variable1[sample1], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h1')
plt.hist(variable1[sample2], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h2')
plt.hist(variable1[sample3], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h3')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.hist(variable2[sample1], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h1')
plt.hist(variable2[sample2], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h2')
plt.hist(variable2[sample3], histtype = 'step', normed = 'yes', label = 'h3')
```

Then I used:

```
plt.legend( ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'], ['Name Of Sample 1', 'Name Of Sample 2', 'Name Of Sample 3'],'upper center')
```

The legend appears, but is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The first is that you are misunderstanding what `label` does.  It does not mark the artists to be accessed via that name, but provides the text used by `legend` if you call `legend` with out any arguments.  The second problem is that `bar` does not have an auto-generated legend handler.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

h1 = ax1.hist(variable1[sample1], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h1')
h2 = ax1.hist(variable1[sample2], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h2')
h3 = ax1.hist(variable1[sample3], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h3')

ha = ax2.hist(variable2[sample1], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h1')
hb = ax2.hist(variable2[sample2], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h2')
hc = ax2.hist(variable2[sample3], histtype='step', normed='yes', label='h3')

# this gets the line colors from the first set of histograms and makes proxy artists
proxy_lines = [matplotlib.lines.Line2D([], [], color=p[0].get_edgecolor()) for (_, _, p) in [h1, h2, h3]]

fig.legend(proxy_lines, ['label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3'])
```

also see http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

Comment: @zhangxaochen the legend code in incredibly powerful and cool but incredibly opaque.  Look into how it does handler dispatching, you can do amazing things.